# Trying to install drivers for my n300 wifi adapter, but I am told to disable secure boot

Tags: drivers, wireless, secure-boot, netgear

trying to install the drivers for my n300 wifi adapter using`sudo apt-get install ndiswrapper-dkms ndisgtk ndiswrapper-common` but when I run it I get a popup that says

"Your system has UEFI Secure Boot enabled.
 │
 │ UEFI Secure Boot is not compatible with the use of third-party drivers.
 │
 │ The system will assist you in toggling UEFI Secure Boot. To ensure that
 │ this change is being made by you as an authorized user, and not by an
 │ attacker, you must choose a password now and then use the same password
 │ after reboot to confirm the change.
 │
 │ If you choose to proceed but do not confirm the password upon reboot,
 │ Ubuntu will still be able to boot on your system but the Secure Boot
 │ state will not be changed.
 │
 │ If Secure Boot remains enabled on your system, your system may still boot but any hardware that requires third-party drivers to work
 │ correctly may not be usable."

What should I do to get this to properly run.

Thanks ahead of time. :)

PS. I am new to Ubuntu so it would be wonderful if I can can have easy to follow instruction's about how to fix it. That being said I'm very good at this kind of thing so I will be able to follow along.

Comment: The easy way is disabling Secure Boot at UEFI settings. Then boot Ubuntu and repeat. Now it should install without the warning. Good luck with ndiswrapper (you will need it).

Comment: What comes after that message? It appears that it is going to help you disable secure boot. However, you should be able to disable secure boot in your BIOS. Is Ubuntu the only OS on the computer or is it dual boot with windows? And also, does the adapter not work out of the box?

Comment: it says <OK>. Also my PC is dual booting with windows 10 but that does not boot correctly. The adapter came with a disk made to run on windows so that is not much help.  How do you enter UEFI settings. @nullmeta

Comment: Have you tried the adapter on Ubuntu to see if it works? Usually you can enter the settings with a hotkey while the system is booting, del or f2 etc.. depends on your device

Comment: @nullmeta It has proprietary interface for the connection settings, it does not go straight through the wifi menu. It lights up, but that seems like all.